# An active access token must be used to query information about the current user

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

I trying to get a Facebook cover by run

`curl https://graph.facebook.com/me/?fields=cover?access_token=*****`

In my terminal - I kept getting

> An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.

Here is my code:

```
public function feed(){

    $id =  Auth::user()->account_id;
    $token_oauth = DB::table('tokens')->where('account_id','=',$id)->first();
    $token = $token_oauth->oauth;
    $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token='.$token;
    $data = shell_exec('curl '.$url);
    $raw = json_decode($data,true);
    return $raw;

}
```

It works. It return list of feed. Then I followed the same steps for my cover photo.

```
public function cover(){

    $id =  Auth::user()->account_id;
    $token_oauth = DB::table('tokens')->where('account_id','=',$id)->first();
    $token = $token_oauth->oauth;

    $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=cover&access_token='.$token;
    $data = shell_exec('curl '.$url);
    $raw = json_decode($data,true);
    return $raw;
}
```

It return

```
{"error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","type":"OAuthException","code":2500,"fbtrace_id":"AOkTdE\/rYNW"}}
```

Comment: The access token must be valid. But it is good that it isn't. Because it would be stupid to post an active access token here

Comment: that token even includes publish_actions. check out your wall ;) - and don´t just remove it from here, because there is an edit history. you need to invalidate it by removing the app in the settings.

Comment: Thanks for tip. I didn't know that it is sensitive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would be correct, the Access Token was valid but you wrote "?" instead of "&" for the second parameter:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/?fields=cover&access_token=*****
```

Btw, you can check if your Token is valid in the Debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: I deleted my token. Went through the whole permission again. Redid as you suggested. I got the same error. What else could it be ?

Comment: Do I missed any permission ?

Comment: you should not need any additional permissions, check out the additional info in my answer. it should actually work even if you just enter the link in the browser, with a valid token.

Comment: I  just check. It's a valid token.  Also, when I tried within the Graph Tool Explorer it work, but when I tried cURL in my terminal. It doesn't work. :(

Comment: If you run curl with that url and your token instead - will it work ?

Comment: i can even just put that url in the browser and it works, so it will definitely work with curl. you should debug curl: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757071/php-debugging-curl - it would also be a good idea to include your code in your question.

Comment: shell_exec? you should not do that. > php.net/manual/book.curl.php

Comment: Dude, you're right. I updated my function to use cURL rather than shell exec. Now it works like a charm :)

Comment: Thanks for your enthusiasm for help !